# how to store data in xml file from textbox in html

Tags: xml

how to store data in xml file from textbox in html.

Comment: Please explain what you are doing.  How are you planing on parsing/reading the xml?

Comment: want to store specific data enter by user in HTML.

Comment: That's not enough of an explanation.  Please provide some samples of input and what you want to store (and where).  My guess is you want the following: 1) the user enters some XML in a text box on an HTML form; 2) you validate it, returning an error message if it's not valid xml; 3) You store the XML in a file.  You didn't say where you want to store it, on the server or the client.  Am I close?

Answer (score 0):

You can't in HTML. What processing software are you using?

Comment: just a simple HTML file, i know how to retrieve data from XML to HTML file using a javascript

Comment: In some very limited contexts, javascript can be given access to the file system of the client, and can save files. These limited contexts are where HTML is being used with something other than a web-browser, such as HTAs. Otherwise HTML and javascript can't save files, or every one of our computers would be full of nothing other than files saying "lol I 0wn j00! 1 am l33t!" because the security would be dreadful.

What you can do, is to POST the form to a server, and have server-side code (PHP, ASP.NET, JSP, CF, and many other options) save this to a file on the server, or othewise store it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to convert the entered xml to html client-side and then submit it to store it. Best would be, accept the data in xml and convert to html on server side and store it. I am sure, if you can do it using javascript, you can do it server-side code.

Comment: The question was asked, to create the local buffer of the input, which will later be posted to the server.